# Showing animated “loading” gif before the actual content appears in Facebox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebox

Showing animated “loading” gif before the actual content appears in Facebox like ajax preloader. is that possible.

From here i am calling to the function

```
   <a href="javascript:;"  onclick="load_crop('<?php echo  $current_large_image_width + 200 ?>','<?php echo $current_large_image_height ;?>')"> Edit Picture</a>
```

And this is my function

```
     function load_crop(wwdth,hhight){


     $.facebox('<iframe FRAMEBORDER="0" height="'+hhight+'"  width="'+wwdth+'"   src="<?php echo $httpTemplatePath;?>/ajax/crop_image2.php? user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['db_user_info']['id']?>" ></iframe>');
                 }
```

IS it possible to put a gif loader before the content of the crop_image2.php show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation itself I think it provides that option:

`$.facebox.settings.loadingImage = '/images/facebox/loading.gif'`

https://github.com/defunkt/facebox#usage